# micrphone for sound level measuring

Tags: microphone

I'am searching for low priced micrphone capsule (< 10$) for a simple sound level measuring.
It should be able to measure levels between 30dB(A) and 90dB(A).

I have already searched for manufacturers, but I have only found cheap capsule. With those capsule I'am not able to measure 30dB. Thera ist mor noise then signal.

Do amnybody knows a manufacture for suitable mics ?

I would be very happy.

Answer (score 1):

Under $10? Tough call. If you're talking about the capsule only, then this is probably an unhelpful answer, as I don't now anything about that. But these measurement/reference microphones start at $55. Apparently there's not a massive difference between the low and high end of the price range in terms of accuracy.

http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/search?sts=ma&Ns=p_PRICE_2%7c0&N=0&srtclk=sort&Ntt=measurement+microphone

Answer (score 0):

If you need to measure db SPL, go in the app-store and have a look for Level-meters. you can put it on your smartphone. I have one for free, it works fine for what it is.
If you need something exact, you probably need to spend a bit more than $10. If you only need it once, ask at rental company for PA-system for a db-meter.

best

Guido